# Find text in WebView and scroll that position Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm implanting code for search text programmatically and scroll that position.
I am finding my text search if its available then i want to click in text programmatically.

```
 binding.webView.setFindListener(object : WebView.FindListener {
        override fun onFindResultReceived(p0: Int, numberOfMatches: Int, p2: Boolean) {
            Log.d("WebView1", "$p0   $numberOfMatches    $p2")
            if (numberOfMatches > 0) {
                if (!loading) {
                    // I want scroll that position       
                  
                }
            }
        }
    })
        binding.webView.findAllAsync("MyTExt")
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about the project and the context of the project. Is a bit empty now.

Comment: Thanks @stefandekraker for reply can you help. I want search urk in webview and wants to click in url.